# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. asp.net entity framework mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Tengo un formulario para realizar un nuevo registro, que al llamarse no trae ninguna información, pero la página no carga por el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nombreMarca, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nombreMarca, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nombreMarca, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @if (Model.mensajeCLS != null)
                {
                    <span class="field-validation-error text-danger">@Model.mensajeCLS</span>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

al retirar

```
                @if (Model.mensajeCLS != null)
                {
                    <span class="field-validation-error text-danger">@Model.mensajeCLS</span>
                }
```

se ejecuta correctamente, la propiedad la uso para decolver un mensaje en caso tal el registro ya exista, y procurar no repetirlo, mi modelo es

```
public class MarcaCLS
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        public int iidMarca { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Marca")]
        [Required]
        public string nombreMarca { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string descripcionMarca { get; set; }
        public int bhabilitado { get; set; }

        //ATRIBUTOS ADICIONALES

        public string mensajeCLS { get; set; }//el atributo en cuestión
    }
```

en mi controller es

```cs
        public ActionResult Ingresar()
        {
            return View();//no cargo ningún atributo al llamar a la vista, formulario en blanco
        }
```

Aparecen resultados a mi pregunta en muchos sitios, pero no son nada parecidos a mi caso, por ende no entiendo como resuelven.

Comment: Hola, en la Acción `Ingresar()` no tienes mas código?

Comment: La tenía tal cual se muestra, corregí con la sugerencia de fredyfx, y funciona.

Comment: Si, claro que funciona. Es que es obvio que si no le pasas a la Vista un Modelo `return View(algunModelo)` no puedes leer una propiedad de algo que es NULL, por eso te hice la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como en el controlador mandas a renderizar la vista sin envíar un modelo, el modelo llega `null`, por lo tanto, `Model.mensajeCLS` será `null` y como quieres acceder a una propiedad de un Modelo sin instanciar, es decir `null`, te lanza ese error.

```
public ActionResult Ingresar()
{
    //Creas el modelo:
    var miModelo = new MarcaCLS();
    //aquí le das miModelo.propiedad = asignas el valor...
    return View(miModelo);
 }
```